# Functions manipulation of variables question (inverse function)

Tags: functions

> I am trying to find the inverse function of the following function:
> $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+5x+5}{x+2}$$

However, I always end up with $y^2$ and $y$ on one side and am unsure how to find $y$ by itself. There is a hint that says to use derivatives, but I do not know in what way they are used here.

Comment: Please add some context. Why do you want the inverse? Maybe for what you have to do you don't need the algebraic equation. It already happened with other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Outlawing $(x = -2),$ you have that

$$x^2 + 5x + 5 = (x+2)y.$$

This can be construed to be a quadratic equation in $x$, where

$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$ will have solutions

$x = \frac{1}{2A} \left[-B \pm\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}\right].$

It is presumed that you will have the constraint on $y$ that $(B^2 - 4AC) \geq 0.$

Note that (for example) the functional equation $x^2 = y$ means that for each positive value of $y$, there are **two** values of $x$ such that $x^2 = y$.  Compare this with the situation where in the above quadratic, $(B^2 - 4AC) > 0.$